# Powershell, shell_exec + Get-Printer

Tags: php, shell, powershell

Estou tentando obter um resultado do servidor B através do servidor A, pelo Powershell no php.
Basicamente estou dando o comando

---

```
PowerShell Get-Printer -ComputerName (Servidor-B) -Name (Impressora) | Format-List
```

Se executo esse comando localmente no servidor A recebo esse resultado.

```
Name                         : teste_1
ComputerName                 : 10.41.13.95
Type                         : Local
ShareName                    :
PortName                     : 192.168.258.258
DriverName                   : Generic / Text Only
Location                     :
Comment                      :
SeparatorPageFile            :
PrintProcessor               : winprint
Datatype                     : RAW
Shared                       : False
Published                    : False
PermissionSDDL               :
RenderingMode                :
KeepPrintedJobs              : False
Priority                     : 1
DefaultJobPriority           : 0
StartTime                    : 0
UntilTime                    : 0
PrinterStatus                : Error
JobCount                     : 1
DisableBranchOfficeLogging   :
BranchOfficeOfflineLogSizeMB :
```

Até ai perfeito, porém se vou através do PHP com Shell_exec através do comando;

```
shell_exec('PowerShell Get-Printer -ComputerName (Servidor-B) -Name (Impressora) | Format-List');
```

O resultado é esse:

```
Get-Printer : An error occurred while performing the specified operation.  See 
the error details for more information.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Printer -computername 10.41.13.95 teste_1 | Format-list
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_Printer:ROOT/StandardCimv2/M 
   SFT_Printer) [Get-Printer], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8007007b,Get-Printer
```

Alguns detalhes:

- Já executei com -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
- Já verifiquei qual o usuário está executando esse comando através do IIS ( Administrador)
- Já tentei executar esse comando dentro de um .ps1 Já tentei colocar esse
  comando dentro de um .bat

Enfim, esgotei minhas ideias, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimenta instalar o PHP no servidores e rodar o powershell de dentro do php q ta nos servidores como ADMIN. 
Se pode pegar o resultado e jogar em banco de dados e resgatar pela aplicacao principal.

Comment: Realmente, fiz um iis no outro servidor e só chamei o comando local pra gerar o relatório que precisava, e funcionou. Obrigado pela dica !!!